# Shopify-Buy-SDK Get Raw Product Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, react-redux

I am looking to build an e-commerce web app using ES6, react, react-redux and yours js-buy-sdk api. My problem is that after fetching all products from shopify and placing them in the store, I seem to no have all data about a product as I would expect, rather only:  `{ attrs, shopClient, serializer, type, config, _memoized }`.

Here is how I am making the call to get products, under a file I named `shopify.js`:

```
import ShopifyBuy from 'shopify-buy';

const shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1403c107adc7e',
  domain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com',
  appId: '6',
});

export function fetchAllProducts() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    shopClient.fetchAllProducts()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('shopClient.fetchAllProducts', data);
        resolve(data);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(new Error('Fetching products error!'));
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Looking at the console.log `shopClient.fetchAllProducts` this is what I get:
[image: chrome console]

I take `data` and place it in the redux store and when I am looking at it, it looks like this:
[image: redux store]

If it is relevant, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rizedr/bcfeaefb2a6082355b9b75a3b5e5fac1) to see the actions I am dispatching and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rizedr/b698649a9bef5842ff420a38553f4fda) where my actions get reduced and placed in the store.

From my understanding, when you do `fetchAllProducts()` method, you get an array of `ProductModel`s, therefore, I suppose in my store gets set the following `{ attrs, shopClient, serializer, type, config, _memoized }` because that is what `ProductModel` stores internally.

**My question is**, is there a way to get a raw object of data from `ProductModel` (with all the relevant product values as presented in the first screenshot and with the data from the Models, such as `ProductOptionModel`, that `ProductModel` relies on) so I can place that my store for stability and sanity reasons?

Shopify API Reference can be found [here](https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/api/classes/ShopifyBuy.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for raw access to the data returned on a product, the `attrs` property contains the API response JSON, without additional logic or models.

However, if possible, I'd suggest organizing your code in such a way that you can leverage these models - we added them because the raw data can be in a particularly confusing format (specifically variants, options, images).

That said, if you want raw data for all products being returned, something like this should do the trick.

```
import ShopifyBuy from 'shopify-buy';

const shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1403c107adc7e',
  domain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com',
  appId: '6',
});

export function fetchAllProducts() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    shopClient.fetchAllProducts()
      .then((products) => {
        resolve(products.map((product) => {
          return product.attrs;
        }));
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(new Error('Fetching products error!'));
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok. Cool so `attrs` should be the correct place to get the raw data from. Thank you for that! The reason I want the raw data is because I want to leverage something like https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ and I don't know yet how that is going to come in play with the Models shopify provides

Answer (score 0):

In your example code you are calling the API with your secret API key? You do understand that this exposes your store to as much abuse you might not want right? Are you sure you know what you're doing there?

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't think it opens to any abuse. For example, you cannot use this API, to, lets say, delete products from your shopify admin. The max someone can do is fetch product info and generate a shopify checkout page with it and eventually buy them, but I wouldn't call that abuse, just smart programmer buyer :D. Here is a full specification what the api does: http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/api/classes/ShopifyBuy.html

Comment: Makes sense... it is a limited key, simply made for getting products. Ok. well done.